# Javascript: drawImage is not taking whole picture

Tags: javascript, drawimage

Here's the code:

```
window.onload = function() {
    var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
    var img = document.getElementById("scream");
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, img.height, img.width, 0, 0, 100, 100);
};
```

Here's the picture:

[image]

I set it to get the whole image by setting img.height and img.width. But still I see that no whole picture is there, only part: bottom part is getting cut. How can I get it? Am I entering wrong value?

[Refer here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_canvas_drawimage3)

Comment: Switch around `img.height` and `img.width`. They're in the wrong order.

Comment: lalala, working. Thank you Mike.

Comment: that was one very stupid question from me

Comment: Everyone gets one ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Arguments of function `drawImage` are
**img** - Specifies the image, canvas, or video element to use
**sx** - Optional. The x coordinate where to start clipping 
**sy** - Optional. The y coordinate where to start clipping 
**swidth** - Optional. The width of the clipped image
**sheight** - Optional. The height of the clipped imag
**x** - The x coordinate where to place the image on the canvas
**y** - The y coordinate where to place the image on the canvas
**width** - Optional. The width of the image to use (stretch or reduce the image)
**height** - Optional. The height of the image to use (stretch or reduce the image)
Correct use of your function will be

```
ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, img.width, img.height, 0, 0, 100, 100);
```